# DIV positioning in google chart tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I got a problem on some div position inside google geochart tooltip.

Some of it looking fine as you can see here

[image]

but somes looking bad as here (if dropname div has one line,the header2 div will move to the right)

[image]

and the code for tooltip below

```js
return
'<br><div id="country">'+ country + " - " + policy +  '<br><br></div> '  + 
'<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
'<div id="dropname">'+dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
'<div id ="header2">Since : </div><div id="date">' + startdate + '</div><br><br><br>' + 
 '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
```

```css
#country{
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:500;
 }

#header1{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#666;
 }
#header2{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#666;
 } 

#date{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:400;
 }
#dropname{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:400;
 display: inline-block;
 height:20px;
 }

#comment{
 font-size:12px;
 font-style:italic;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#06F;
 }
```

**Which position should I set for each div here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `display: inline-block;` from the `#dropname` declaration. This will let the divs go back to their normal block level, and they will be forced to display one on top of the other.

Also try not to use `<br><br>`. That's not considered best practise. Instead add some margin, so your final declaration would be:

```
#dropname{
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

In fact I don't like the look of the artificially set "height" there either, so I would remove that too! :)

Comment: tried that but still the same,I think because I set main DIV{display:inline-block},but I set that to fix another div on page , you can see the page here http://sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/test1menu.html if I remove ,the radiobutton and img will position wrong.I don't know what to do now,hope you could help me,thanks.

Comment: If you added that to fix something else. Then on that "something else" add a new class, and target that class with the display: inline-block style. You really shouldn't do something as "wide ranging" as div {inline-block } You need to target the specific you need to do that on, either by class or id.

Comment: OH OK. In fact add "display: block" to the code above. That will "beat" the div {display: inline } you have set elsewhere.